# pretty print a list of variables and values in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

i would like to dump the names of variables and their values to stderr. the following code fragment accomplishes the task for variables one at a time:

```
int x=4; int y=2;
#define DUMP_VALUE(x) fprintf( stderr, "%s\n" \
  ( #x "=" + std::to_string(x) ).c_str() )
DUMP_VALUE(x);
DUMP_VALUE(y);
```

outputs:

```
x=4
y=2
```

so far so good. but... how do we expand that idea to a list of variables? for example, this code fragment:

```
int x=4; int y=2; int z=19;
DUMP_VALUES(x,y,z);
```

would produce this desired output:

```
x=4, y=2, z=19
```

the problem is... what combination of macros and c++11 variadic templates could do the trick?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why not use `cerr`?

Comment: old coders learn new tricks slowly. ;->

Comment: Your existing version can be made more efficient by putting `#x "="` in the format string

Answer (score 1):

You could define a variadic template with something like this:

```
template <class T>
void dump(T t)
{
  std::cout << "val=", << t << " ";
}

template <class T, class... Args>
void dump(T t, Args... args)
{
  dump(t);
  dump(args);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = 3;
dump(x, y, z);
```

Output:

```
val=1, val=2, val=3
```

You'll have to pass in the name of the variable somehow while calling dump if you want that printed out.

Here's a decent reference site with some variadic example: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Comment: thanks but... the desired output would be: x=1, y=2, z=3. not val=1, val=2, val=3. the latter is easy. as you've noted. the former is less so.